# How can I delete files owned by other user?

Tags: permissions, root, chmod, forge

I have a custom-made laravel command, which creates some files in `/storage/app/something` directory every hour (`forge` user owns them).

After that laravel user can't delete these files from disk via admin panel, because he is not owner of them.

User can delete them only after using `sudo chmod -R storage/app/something`.

How can I make this directory editable for `forge` user and for `www-data` user both?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following commands

```
sudo chown -R forge /storage/app/something
sudo chgrp -R www-data /storage/app/something
sudo chmod 2770 /storage/app/something
```

The first command makes `forge` the owner of the directory.

The second command changes the group of the directory to `www-data`, meaning that anyone in the `www-data` group can access the directory with the group permissions. Notably this group contains the user `www-data`, so it should give `www-data` access.

The third command does the following: Gives the user (in this case `forge`) access level 7 (rwx). Gives the group (in this case `www-data`) access level 7 (rwx). Gives all other users access level 0 (---), which means other users cannot access the directory (replace it with 5 to give them read-only permission).

Finally the `2` in the `chmod` command sets what is called the `setgid` bit on the directory, which means all new files will inherit the group of the directory, instead of the group of whoever created the file. This means the files will have group `www-data` too, allowing the group to access the files.

---

Of course you could also just do `sudo chmod 777 /storage/app/something`, which would allow anyone full access to the directory, but this is a bad practice.

Comment: I don't seem to get around the problem, as soon as files gets deleted and recreated by forge, www-data lose the permission unless I run all 3 commands again